# CSS3 based Slide-In Navigation

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions, css-transforms

I'm using a CSS3 based slide-in navigation.
The Navigation currently slides in from left-to-right with necessary transitions at an angle. I would like to use the same effect, but I need the slide to happen from right-to-left.

I found this snippet from codepen, I tried making changes to it, but I'm unable to achieve it.

If anyone could solve this for me, it'll be of great help.

Here is a quick [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s4curn0v) to my code -

```
.navigation-menu__bars, .navigation-menu__bars::before, .navigation-menu__bars::after {
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 1px;
  height: 2px;
  width: 25px;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  display: block;
  transition: all .3s;
}
.navigation-menu {
  background-color: transparent;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  width: 527px;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  transition: transform .3s .3s;
}
.navigation-menu::before {
  background: #4E567E;
  content: '';
  height: 400%;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(40deg);
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
}
.navigation-menu--open {
  transform: translateX(0);
}
.navigation-menu--open .navigation-menu__bars {
  background-color: transparent;
}
.navigation-menu--open .navigation-menu__bars::before, .navigation-menu--open .navigation-menu__bars::after {
  top: 0;
}
.navigation-menu--open .navigation-menu__bars::before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.navigation-menu--open .navigation-menu__bars::after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.navigation-menu--open .menu-list__item {
  opacity: 1;
  transition-delay: 1.25s;
}
.navigation-menu__toggle {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  right: -40px;
  top: 5px;
  width: 30px;
}
.navigation-menu__bars::before, .navigation-menu__bars::after {
  content: '';
}
.navigation-menu__bars::before {
  left: 0;
  top: -8px;
}
.navigation-menu__bars::after {
  left: 0;
  top: 8px;
}

.menu-list {
  padding: 60px 20px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}
.menu-list__item {
  margin: 40px 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .5s .5s;
}
```

Comment: > `but I need the slide to happen from right-to-left.` So do you need it to be on the right side or keep it on the left side with the opposite transition? Share some progress you did.

Comment: @extempl I need it to be on the right side with transition happening from right to left. I didn't understand the transforms that were used to create the effect.

Comment: So the first thing you should at least change the layout to be right-sided

Comment: @extempl I solved it by myself! :)

Comment: Great. High five!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 3 and half hours of struggle, I solved it by myself.

```js
(function($) {
  $('.js-nav-menu-toggle').on('click', function() {
    $(this).parents('.navigation-menu').toggleClass('navigation-menu--open');
  });
  
  $('html').on('click', function(e) {
    if(!$(e.target).closest('.js-nav-menu').length &&
      ($('.js-nav-menu').hasClass('navigation-menu--open'))) {
        $('.js-nav-menu').removeClass('navigation-menu--open');
    }
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
body {
  background: #000;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  color: #fff;
  height: 100vh;
}

.navigation-menu__bars, .navigation-menu__bars::before, .navigation-menu__bars::after {
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 1px;
  height: 2px;
  width: 25px;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  display: block;
  transition: all .3s;
}

.navigation-menu {
  background-color: transparent;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  width: 554px;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  transition: transform .3s .3s;

  /*vk*/
  right: 0;
  transform: translateX(92%)
}
.navigation-menu::before {
  background: #4E567E;
  content: '';
  height: 400%;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(40deg);
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 0;

  /*vk*/
  transform: translate(-43%, -50%) rotate(-40deg);
}
.navigation-menu--open {
  transform: translateX(0);
}
.navigation-menu--open .navigation-menu__bars {
  background-color: transparent;
}
.navigation-menu--open .navigation-menu__bars::before, .navigation-menu--open .navigation-menu__bars::after {
  top: 0;
}
.navigation-menu--open .navigation-menu__bars::before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.navigation-menu--open .navigation-menu__bars::after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.navigation-menu--open .menu-list__item {
  opacity: 1;
  transition-delay: 1s;
}
.navigation-menu__toggle {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  /*right: -40px;*/
  top: 5px;
  width: 30px;

  /*vk*/
  z-index: 9999;
}
.navigation-menu__bars::before, .navigation-menu__bars::after {
  content: '';
}
.navigation-menu__bars::before {
  left: 0;
  top: -8px;
}
.navigation-menu__bars::after {
  left: 0;
  top: 8px;
}

.menu-list {
  padding: 60px 20px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;

  /*vk*/
  width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
.menu-list__item {
  margin: 40px 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .5s .5s;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .navigation-menu {
    min-width: 240px;
    width: 80%;
  }
  .navigation-menu::before {
    width: 110%;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .navigation-menu {
    background-color: #4E567E;
    min-width: 240px;
    width: 80%;
  }
  .navigation-menu::before {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(45deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navigation-menu js-nav-menu">
  <div class="navigation-menu__toggle js-nav-menu-toggle">
    <span class="navigation-menu__bars"></span>
  </div>
  <ul class="menu-list">
    <li class="menu-list__item">Menu Item 1</li>
    <li class="menu-list__item">Menu Item 2</li>
    <li class="menu-list__item">Menu Item 3</li>
    <li class="menu-list__item">Menu Item 4</li>
    <li class="menu-list__item">Menu Item 5</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use animations in css.the best example shown in w3school website.
here is a best example of animation you can use

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-animation: myfirst 5s 2; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
  -webkit-animation-direction: alternate; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
  animation: myfirst 0.5s;
  animation-direction: ri;
}

/* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
@-webkit-keyframes myfirst {
  0%   {background: red; left: 200px; top: 0px;}
  50%  {background: yellow; left: 50px; top: 0px;}
  75% {background:red; left:25px;top:0px;}
  100% {background: red; left: 0px; top: 0px;}
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>The animation-direction Property</h1>

<p>Play the animation forwards first, then backwards:</p>
<div></div>
<p><strong>Note:</strong> The animation-direction property is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions.</p>

</body>
</html>
```